# vb.net validate days from selected date fields

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, date

I have two textboxes which are date pickers. `tbStartDate` and `tbEndDate`. The user should only pick a date that starts on a Monday and ends on a Friday, e.g.

```
tbStart.text = 05/11/2012 (Mon 5th November 2012)
tbEndDate.text = 09/11/2012 (Fri 11th November 2012)
```

I need to validate that the start and end dates are Monday and Friday respectively.

I am using asp.net (Visual Basic). What is the best solution to my problem?
Thanks

**RESOLVED:**

```
Sub GetDayOfWeek()
Dim MyDate As Date = "2012/11/04"
        If MyDate.DayOfWeek.ToString() = "Sunday" Then
            Response.Write("Cannot be a weekend!")
         Else
            Response.Write("Weekday Detected!")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: A [`CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx).

Comment: Good idea! Any suggestions how to detect if StartDate is not Monday using vb.net? Thnx

Comment: `Dim notMonday As Boolean = StartDate.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Monday`

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub GetDayOfWeek()
Dim MyDate As Date = "2012/11/04"
        If MyDate.DayOfWeek.ToString() = "Sunday" Then
            Response.Write("Cannot be a weekend!")
         Else
            Response.Write("Weekday Detected!")
        End If
    End Sub
```